Can I ask this question on using Optuna with nested cross-validation for multiple model selection here?
I think this is in-topic, but I just wanted to double-check in case you think I need to move to the more AI-related groups:

How to perform hyperparameter tuning and model selection with Optuna and nested cross-validation
I have a list of regression models and a dataset. I want to do two things at the same time:

find the optimal hyperparameters for each regression model with Optuna
select the regression model with lowest generalization error E (error on unseen data)

If I use a single cross-validation loop to do both things, I will underestimate E since I'm using the same data to tune hyperparameters, select model and estimate the generalization error. I would thus like to use nested cross-validation, but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly.

etc. etc. I would then add my Python code (struggling to make it reproducible atm without including private data, but I'm on the right track).

At a glance, this is quite broad. You're basically asking 2 questions already. It definitely needs some sample code.

@Cerbrus I will definitely add the sample code in the actual question. Do you think I should also add it in this Meta question?

For context, that might help answering this question, yeah.

@Cerbrus sure. Then I'll do it, but I'm not sure I'll be able to do it today. It's proving to be a bit complicated. Tomorrow I have a long haul flight, but rest assured that if I don't manage to write the code today, you'll have it by Thursday. Apologies for the delay

I am not sure if this would be on-topic for Stack Overflow. If your problem in not about how to write code for what you want. You mention implementation, but is it really the code or general approach? It looks like it would be more suitable for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://ai.stackexchange.com/ or https://genai.stackexchange.com/ I am listing all of them as I am not familiar on which one would your question be a best fit.

@DalijaPrasnikar I'm interested in actual code, non just a general approach. I (think I) know the general approach, but I'm not sure how to put it in code. Your comment, like the ones by Cerbrus, convince me that I need to add the code in this Meta question, but unfortunately that may require a day or two. I'll do it anyway

In that case it is likely that it would be on topic here. Adding code would help.
